# Pull request numbers higher than expected on my repo?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I just noticed that the numbers on the two (and only two) pull requests are #13 and #17.

[Like this](https://github.com/spikespaz/search-deflector/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Aclosed).

Shouldn't they be named #1 and #2? This confuses me and I wasn't sure where to ask this.

Comment: Is there any chance that others might have created, and then rejected, other pull requests?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not at all. I am the sole maintainer and collaborator of this repository, nobody else had anything to do with it except for the one merged pull that changed one line.

Comment: GitHub numbers everything sequentially: your first issue or pull request or whatever is #1, your second is #2, and so on. If someone created issues 1-12 the first pull request would be #13.

Comment: @torek But issues and pulls share order?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "share order". Once I've made issue #123, I cannot make a pull request #123, the next *thing* I make is #124, whether that's a new issue or a new pull request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But issues and pulls share order?

Yes: see the [GitHub API List issues](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues) and [List PR](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests): the id they return is unique.

If you go and create a new issue on [moby/moby](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/new) and type in it:

```
#37915
#37916
```

The first ID will be the one of a PR, the second one an issue, and the preview will show you the proper URL:

[image: pull-request ID] vs. [image: issue ID]

That way, you don't have to qualify a number `#xxx`: its unique ID will reference the PR or issue you want.